# use CMake to generate a multiple-configuration Eclipse CDT project: failed

Tags: cmake, eclipse-cdt

I have c++ projects developed in windows with VS2013, now I am trying to use eclipse in Linux.

I create a hello-word application and use CMake-GUI(2.8.11) to generate eclipse-cdt(4.4) project. The generated eclipse project can not have both the Debug and Release configurations : import the generated project into eclipse-cdt, and select the menu “Build Configurations->Set Active” : aha, it is grey! which means no way to switch between Debug and Release.

Why CMake can not generate a multiple-configuration eclipse project? Or I am doing something wrong.

I get some info from http://www.voom.net/use-cmake-with-eclipse/comment-page-1#comment-171974

Thanks.

Comment: What [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) are you using? Ninja? GNU Makefiles? If you use `Ninja Multi-Config` that might get you what you want.